# Create a DataGridView and set DataSource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I got a list of objects - lets say of type `Person` and a `DataGridView` instantiated in the constructor of my form.

```
public Form() {

    List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
    DataGridView.DataSource = Persons;
}
```

By default the `DataGridView` will display one column for every property (except for complex types?) of my `Person` class.

But I just want it to show maybe two columns `FirstName` and `LastName`.

I know i can add columns to my `DataGridView` programmatically like this:

```
DataGridView.Columns.Add("Firstname", "Firstname");
```

But I dont want to add my items like this

```
foreach (var item in Persons) {
            DataGridView.Rows.Add(item.FirstName);
        }
```

I would rather like to set the `DataSource` of my `DataGridView`. Whats the best way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

My List is going to be updated or reset etc. I would like to just update the List and refresh the binding. I dont want to handle some invisible IndexRow in my DataGrid, thats why i dont want to iterate through all the items and add a row for everyone. I hope you understand my problem now

Comment: Why not just set the columns manually in the form?  You say you know you can add them programmatically by specifically adding an individual column, what is wrong with that approach?  If you are wanting to set the columns on your datasource itself and have the grid just "know", that is a bad practice (keep you data separate from your presentation) and I would not recommend it.

Comment: Construct your data source as you wish and set it as `DataGridView.SataSource`

Answer (score 0):

If you only plan on using it in one place in your program, I would use the Browsable attribute on your properties and set all of them to False except Person.Firstname and Person.lastName

If you need to use it in multiple places, you could make a person collection and expose a DataTable object called FirstLastNameTable or something like that, and just make a DataTable on the fly and bind to that.

Comment: What is your solution in case when you want to use the same data type in another place in your application but needed to show all properties?